# Fetching audio peak values using JavaScript/python

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, reactjs

Hi I am trying to get peak values of a 3 seconds audio, I need something like for which second the peak value is what,

like this

```
time - 0.01 : peak -1
time - 0.11 : peak -10
time - 0.21 : peak -4
time - 0.31 : peak -8
...
time - 3.00 : peak -2
```

I have tried waveform.js but it only provides peak values not time, Same with offline audioContext which i tried provides me the peak values but not the time value

Please help me out

Even in python if i can get these values, it will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by `for which second the peak value is what`. At any single point of time there is only 1 value. Are you looking for the local peak value for each second?

Comment: @ManavM: consider a audio is 1 second, I need ten values, like 0.1second the peak value is 1, 0.2 second the peak value is 2. something like that

Comment: So you want to know what was the highest value in 0-0.01, 0.01-0.02 etc? Peak values exist on intervals..not discrete points of time